# The very same simple logic doesn't work when written in a different way in rtf OBIP template

Tags: xml, ms-word, rtf, bi-publisher

So, I had two boolean variables (let's say x and y) and a very simple code in an rtf OBIP template like that:

```
<?if x="false"?>
   <?if y="false"?>
      Some text1
   <?end if?>
   <?if y="true"?>
      Some text2
   <?end if?>
<?end if?>
<?if x="true" and y="false"?>
      Some text3
<?end if?>
```

And this logic fails (no text is written and in fact, it collapses the whole row in a table where this block is put in) in a specific case of x = true with no difference of y's value.
However, if I change it to something like this:

```
<?if x="false" and y = "false"?>
   Some text1
<?end if?>
<?if x="false" and y="true"?>
   Some text2
<?end if?>
<?if x="true" and y="false"?>
   Some text3
<?end if?>
```

It works perfectly.
It's the same logic, just written in a different way. Note that the template is quite complicated, but after digging into the bug I was working with, it came down to that problem. There were no syntax errors whatsoever, two people doublechecked everything, and it's THAT confusing.
What might have been the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the `IF` appears to be wrong

You have

```
<?if x="false"?>
```

Should be

```
<?if:x="false"?>
```